# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not always called after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths even for valid indexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with cells that can be expanded when the user taps a subview on the cell.

To expand the cell, I call **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** passing an array of the cell's indexPath.

I find that this works in most of the cases but sometimes a cell doesn't update. 
Digging around, I discovered that in the case of these faulty cells, there's never a call to **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

The normal sequence for a cell's expansion, as I understand it, is

```
*expandCellAtIndexPath: -> reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: -> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:*
```

Between **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** and **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, there's a call to tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: where I include the updated height of the affected cell.

The sequence is mostly the same (as far as code I can step-through) for the faulty case, except after **heightForRowAtIndexPath** on the table, **cellForRowAtIndexPath** never gets called.

The result is that the table view expands the cell but the content has not been updated in the faulty case, resulting in a poor user experience.

Has anyone experienced this problem with cell updates on a UITableView or am I missing something obvious?

- A couple of things to note:

  1. The indexPath for each cell is valid when reloadRowsAtIndexPaths executes (it's not nil and points to a cell in the tableview) in both
     functioning and faulty scenarios.
  2. My tests suggest that the same row always triggers the fault condition during expansion regardless of where it is positioned
     within the visible portion of the table view.

Comment: Are you perhaps changing the number of rows in the section between the two calls?  Put a stop in numberOfRowsInSection and see how often it's called and what you're returning.

Comment: No, the number of rows remains the same for each section before and after the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths call.

Comment: You checked that to be sure?

Comment: Yeah, I log the count for each section and it remains constant before and after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.
The total row count also remains constant.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got things to work though I still can't exactly tell what UITableView was doing.

High-level:

1. Had 2 bugs, one core data related, the other a poor assumption in
   computing row heights that was exposed by the former.
2. Unfortunately both bugs manifested themselves when a cell was
   expanded.  In the case I was experiencing, it caused the target
   cell's position to be pushed outside the tableview's visible region.
3. Somehow (and this part I don't get), UITableView didn't actually
   shift the cell out of the visible region but it stopped sending it
   the cellForRowAtIndexPath message (which is expected, as the cell is
   no longer visible).

Once I tracked down the bug the rendering issue went away.

By the way, thanks Hot Licks, your suggestions got me adding lots of log messages for all cells within the affected section, which is how I discovered that the height of one of the predecessor cells was way off.

If anyone runs into something with a similar symptom, I'd recommend implementing the

```
tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

method of the UITableViewDelegate protocol and checking to see if the cell that's no longer receiving **cellForRowAtIndexPath** ends up as an argument to that message.